# UIActivityIndicatorView doesn't appear anymore during web service call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

Yesterday I added a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to my iOS application and everything was fine, now I'm trying to run the same application but the `UIActivityIndicatorView` is not showing anymore and the `agenda` view (which calls the web service) takes very long time (more than yesterday) to appear and often it does not appear at all. How can I fix this problem, please? Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)agenda:(id)sender {

    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
    spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    // how we stop refresh from freezing the main UI thread
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

        // do our long running process here
        // [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];
        AgendaViewController *agenda = [[ AgendaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        // do any UI stuff on the main UI thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [spinner stopAnimating];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:agenda animated:YES];           
        });

    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);

}
```

Comment: That code looks alright to me. I would advise commenting out the `queue` code and check if the spinner shows up (do not `stopAnimating`). The first culprit that comes to mind is the "long running process" code that you are not showing.

Comment: When I comment the `queue` code the spinner shows up even by using
 `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10];` when queue code is uncommented  
 but it doesn't appear when I add this code : 
`AgendaViewController *agenda = [[ AgendaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`
it seems like the problem caused by this line that is the code I want to add in the " long running process"
Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Try adding the spinner subview on the main thread using a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() block.

Comment: OK, try to give your `AgendaViewController` an identifier and instantiate your object like that. I assume you are using `storyboards`. Here is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8853872/2150138).

Comment: No I'm using xib files

Comment: I don't know why when I do it like this, code works fine: 
`dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        
        // do our long running process here
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; // adding this line makes the uiactivityindicatorview appears
       
        AgendaViewController *agenda = [[ AgendaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Comment: Then you need to pass the `xib` filename to the `initWithNibName:`. Calling `initWithNibName:` with `nil` arguments is the same as just calling `init`. It will create an object directly from the `class` definition but it will not have anything from the `xib` files.

Comment: I believe that when you "uncomment" the `sleepForTimeInterval` line "you think" it works because it has enough time to show the spinner before pushing a "blank" `agenda` VC.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks strange to me.

If `AgendaViewController` is a `UIViewController` then it should be touched on the main thread. 
Hence I would separe code that you uses for retrieve data from your service to the code related to `UIViewController`.

I would modify the code as follows. This is a possible solution.

```
// spinner could become a strong property int the presenter controller
self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
self.spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
self.spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.spinner];
[self.spinner startAnimating];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

// moved the dispatch_queue into an instance variable or property but do not forget to release
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

    // call the service here to retrieve serverData

    // do any UI stuff on the main UI thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if(strongSelf) {
            AgendaViewController *agenda = [[ AgendaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
            agenda.serverData = serverData;
            [strongSelf.navigationController pushViewController:agenda animated:YES];
            [strongSelf.spinner stopAnimating];     
        }    
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to be related to the way you are instantiating your **agenda** VC. If you are using `xib` files, then you need to pass the name of the `xib` to your `initWithNibName`. Calling `initWithNibName:` with `nil` arguments is the same as just calling `init`. It will create an object directly from the class **definition** but it will not have anything that you customly created on the `xib` file.

I believe that when you **uncomment** the `sleepForTimeInterval:` line "you think" it works because it has enough time to show the spinner before pushing a **blank** agenda VC.

Note: The only way the `initWithNibName:` works with `nil` arguments (which I still think you should just call  `init` instead), is when the `xib` file is named after your `VC`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444805/2150138).

### Update

Based on the commenst to this answer, your long running process is not inside the `async` code but in the `viewDidLoad:` method inside your `AgendaViewController`. Therefore, one solution would be:

1. Remove the `async` code completely from the `action` and replace it by just the `init/push` logic of the `AgendaViewController`.
2. Add/start the `UIActivityIndicatorView` inside your `AgendaViewController`'s `viewDidLoad:`.
3. Make your call to the **mySQL** DB (the actual "long running process").
4. Stop the **spinner/activityIndicator** when you receive the data.

I don't know how you are implementing your **mySQL** call (web service/api) but it should provide either a `block` or a `protocol` method that gets called when it is done. That is where you need to add your logic to stop the **spinner**.

Comment: Thank you Callistino, I changed `nil` by the name of the xib file, it worked fine in the first test and then I tried to run the application again, and same problem returns, the `uictivityindicatorview`disappeared and after few seconds the `agenda`view appears normally, same thing with the code int the question, it works fine yesterday but not now anymore, don't know why !

Comment: Then you need to show us what your "long running" process is. I suspect that you are doing some `async` operation that doesn't finish before you try to instantiate the `agenda` VC. If that is the case, you need to use the `async` operation `return/block` to instantiate your `agenda` VC. Then, you will not need **GCD** at all.

Comment: My long running process is to declare the `agenda`view and then push it from the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{`block
 (the `agenda`calls data from `mysql`database in it's `viewdidload`method this is why it takes time to load and display its content) so the " long running process " contains just this code : `AgendaViewController *agenda = [[ AgendaViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AgendaViewController" bundle:nil];
        agenda.lat = lat;
        agenda.longt = longt;
        agenda.agendaBackOffice = @"0";
        agenda.agendaStatut= @"";
        agenda.userId = @"";`

Comment: That is the problem, your are **initialazing** your VC on the the `async` process but the **actual long running process** doesn't occur until the `viewDidLoad:` which in turn doesn't occur until the `VC` is pushed onto the `navigationController`. In other words, your view is displayed (**pushed**) before the data is loaded and way after the `activityIndicatorView` has been stopped.

Comment: Thanx for responding, but how can I fix this problem ?