# ios 7.0: button action crashed

Tags: ios, objective-c

In story board, I'm trying to add a button on a scroll view, and assigning an action to the button

```
- (IBAction)likeFood:(id)sender{NSLog(@"liked")};
```

But it crashed when I run it on iPhone simulator, and the output says :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception `'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: [<DetailFoodViewController 0xf034aa0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key like.'
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: please share your code!

Comment: [ask] - Please add the code for your button action.

Comment: there is nothing inside, just - (IBAction)likeFood:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"liked");
}

Comment: Post the stack trace then.

Comment: possible duplicate of [setValue:forUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793162/setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means you are sending a message "setLike" to DetailFoodViewController when that class doesn't have that method / property.

Somewhere you are doing something like `[controller setLike:(somevalue)];` but you don't have a property called "like"