# Exception on coding-compilant value for non-existing button

Tags: ios, storyboard, nsunknownkeyexception

I have performed some changes on my storyboard file and deleted a bar button. Before deleting, I removed all the connections in both storyboards for both screens.

Next, I deleted all the code, connected with this button.

Now I'm getting an error on startup:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
'[<TTPDepartmentViewController 0xe805bd0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: 
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key nextButton.'
```

I've checked for this `nextButton` all over the source code of storyboards and all. No sign, no connections, still this error bumps out. More, I've reseted the simulation. What can I do?

UPD: I totally removed the problematic (as I thought) storyboard and the problem still appears, even that other storyboards do not contain these views with this key at all.

UPD2: [image: unleashedprop]

As you can see the connection thing is not filled, so there should be no connection. When I uncomment this line it builds and runs, though it is not obviously used at all.

Comment: Try cleaning and building your project?

Comment: @duci9y tried just now, no changes

Answer (score 0):

select file's owner in your document outline window and switch to connections inspectors tab. More likely than not, you will see a connection with a yellow exclamation sign on it saying "nextButton". Just remove that and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this was the case now:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21883809/2084479

I don't know, why but even before this bug appeared, I had "Main" in my Main Interface in the deploy info, but this was working. Now, I've updated to some other value (in the answer it's told that you can even leave it blank) and this fixed the build.

Comment: strange ! I ve seen quite a few instances of this here at stackoverflow but this never happened to me. Its always been a faulty outlet connection. Mind telling me which Xcode version are you using ?

Comment: Sure, Version 5.1.1 (5B1008)