# undefined key error thrown during segue Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am simple trying to trigger a segue from one view controller to another when the user presses a button, but I get the following error code when I try.

```
2014-12-09 15:38:32.559 Hokulia[2697:172401] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<selectCombos 0x7ffb11e5f030> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f48f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104be1bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104f48b79 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010477e7b3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e92e80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010374fc7d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001035aef98 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001035af588 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001035af7f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001035afc8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001035d3507 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 633
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001035df3fe -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001035dff47 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000103725509 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000103503973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    15  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105daade8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    16  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105d9fa0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    17  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105d9f87e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    18  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105d0d63e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    19  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105d0e74a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    20  QuartzCore                          0x0000000105d0edb5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e7ddc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e7dd20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e73b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e73486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001058e19f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010348a420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    27  Hokulia                             0x0000000102b25ca3 main + 115
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107c4a145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Oh, fyi I made the segue in IB no programatically

Comment: Check the view outlet is connected correctly, also check whether there is any broken outlets

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793162/setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k