# Picker View from text field is failing

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I am trying to display a picker view upon clicking inside my UITextField.

This is my code so far:

import UIKit

class Anywhere2ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var climateText: UITextField!

var climates = ["Hot","Warm","Cold"]
var picker = UIPickerView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
    climateText.inputView = picker

}

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
        return climates.count
    }

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return climates[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    climateText.text = climates[row]
}
```

But when I go to Build and Run, I continue to get this Failure alert!

### **2016-03-19 11:44:28.303 ABH[20523:8939349] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key pickerTextField1.'**

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reasonthis-class-is-not-key-valu) out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested it and it works fine. I think you problem is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793162/setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k).
Try to rebind the textfield outlet or do as described in the link.
Somehow your @IBOutlet weak var climateText: UITextField! is not connected.
You can click on the textfield in xcode and then on the connections inspector and then check referenced outlets.

[image]

Comment: This worked! Thank you sir! Everything begins to run together after staring for to long.

Comment: Please set my answer as correct answer and vote up if you feel I helped you