# How do I find the xib that's causing an NSUnknownKeyException?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xib

I have a xib file that's causing `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` to be called, like in this question:

[setValue:forUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793162/setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k/13812660)

But I don't know how to find the xib file that's causing the exception.

Comment: What do you mean "How to find XIB file"? You should be able to see in your files created in project navigator. The files with extension ".xib" or ".storyboard"

Comment: In `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key LoginScreen`. You have to search where did you set previously `LoginScreen`. That's where. Else, you can open each .xib, show them as Source Code (right click on it, open as), and look for `<outlet property="LoginScreen"`. You could also use Terminal to search for them (filter .xib/.storyboard and find which one is the culprit)

Comment: [Graham Perks's answer on the linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13812660/603977) addresses exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setValue:forUndefinedKey: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793162/setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k)