# UIWebView is crashing application

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, swift2

I am trying to create a WebView in a storyboard Swift 2.3 iOS application. However, whenever I navigate to the View with the WebView, the app crashes. I am posting the storyboard and code for the WebView. Does this give any indications as to what I am doing wrong?

Storyboard scene:

```
<!--WebView View-->
    <scene sceneID="oin-Tm-kjC">
        <objects>
            <viewController title="WebView View" id="iti-7S-ISp" customClass="webViewViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <layoutGuides>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="3bg-3D-Wcg"/>
                    <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="Mnm-nM-yzb"/>
                </layoutGuides>
                <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="gnf-vw-fwi">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <subviews>
                        <webView contentMode="scaleToFill" fixedFrame="YES" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="rVb-rt-chb">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="64" width="375" height="603"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.36078431370000003" green="0.38823529410000002" blue="0.4039215686" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                            <connections>
                                <outlet property="delegate" destination="iti-7S-ISp" id="E7m-JN-oGx"/>
                            </connections>
                        </webView>
                    </subviews>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                </view>
                <connections>
                    <outlet property="webView" destination="rVb-rt-chb" id="ldC-1p-1XM"/>
                </connections>
            </viewController>
            <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="Dj4-qu-aUe" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
        </objects>
        <point key="canvasLocation" x="248.80000000000001" y="-631.0344827586207"/>
    </scene>
```

webViewViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class webViewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    let url = "https://www.google.com"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nsUrl = NSURL(string: url)
        let nsUrlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: nsUrl!)
        webView.loadRequest(nsUrlRequest)
    }
}
```

I see this line in the console: *"Unknown class webViewViewController in Interface Builder file"*

Followed by: *"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key webViewViewController.'".*

Additionally, the app runs fine if I remove the coupling to the webViewViewController.swift. In which case it just shows an empty UIWebView.

Comment: Share app crash reason (it may print a statement in console area) when your app crashes

Comment: @RyanHeitner he's using `NSURL` & `NSURLRequest` because he's still using the soon-to-be-totally-gone-as-of-Xcode-8.3 Swift 2.3

Comment: @RyanHeitner From the storyboard XML it seems the outlet is hooked

Comment: Thanks @Monster I was a little quick to post.. I have added to description.

Comment: I have this wierd feeling that `webViewViewController` might be conflicting with something *within* the iOS SDK, but I don't know this for sure yet.  In the meantime, a style recommendation for Nik:  class names [**should start with upper-case-letters**](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/9-confusing-naming-conventions-for-beginners--net-15584).

Comment: pblm is navigating check the class name `navigate to the View with `webViewViewController` is connected or not

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793162/setvalueforundefinedkey-this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-k

Comment: Share snapshot of storyboard (webViewController) with connection inspector & Class Name and storyboard id. Either you may have set wrong connection in connection inspector or You class could not be connected to your project

Comment: can you attach your project , it is easy ti resolve

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @MichaelDautermann I just tried removing, adding new UIWebView, and coupling to same class with a unique name. Same result.

Comment: this question hasn't had attention in a couple hours.  Another suggestion from me:  change the name from `webViewViewController` (or `WebViewViewController`) to something else, and make sure you make the matching change to the name of your custom class in your Storyboard.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelDautermann I tried 'starting over' using a different class name with no risk of conflict. It did not have any effect.

Comment: I ended up leaving the UIWebView out of the storyboard entirely and adding it programmatically instead. This works perfectly, but I will leave the question open, and try any other suggestions that may come in.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class webViewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    let url = "https://www.google.com"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let nsUrl = NSURL(string: url)
        let nsUrlRequest = NSURLRequest(url: nsUrl! as URL)
        webView.loadRequest(nsUrlRequest as URLRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: `URL` & `URLRequest` isn't compatible with Swift 2.3, iAnkit.  This isn't going to fix his problem.

Comment: Nik says in the first sentence of his question he's writing this for Swift 2.3.

Comment: problem in class name